# While loop validation in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to add validation to my application in Python.

Basically I want to make sure their input is a number and if its not, it should just keep asking them the input question until they get it.

This is what I got which only works for like 2 tries, I believe its because it checks if its not null.

I know this is a lot of code. Not sure of another way to do this, any ideas?

```
while amount != "":
    try:
        val = int(amount)
        while counter < int(amount):
            counter = counter + 1
            ran = ran + 1
            num3 = input(str(ran) + ". Input: ")
            try:
               val = int(num3)
            except ValueError:
               num3 = input(str(ran) + ". Input: ")
            numbers.append(num3)
        print("")
        home()
    except ValueError:
        amount=input("How many numbers are in your list? ")
        while counter < int(amount):
            counter = counter + 1
            ran = ran + 1
            num3 = input(str(ran) + ". Input: ")
            try:
               val = int(num3)
            except ValueError:
               num3 = input(str(ran) + ". Input: ")
            numbers.append(num3)
        print("")
        home()
```

Comment: What does the `home` function do?

Comment: Just restarts. But that doesn't got much to do with the error.

Comment: I'm not sure what the function is supposed to do as there seems to be some nested asking for values. The same code twice seems to hint that you are doing more complicated things than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

how bout

```
def get_int_input(txt):
    x = raw_input(txt)
    while not x.isdigit():
        x = raw_input("Invalid Input. %s"%txt)
    return int(x)

numbers = [get_int_input("%s input:"%i) for i in range(get_int_input("Enter Number Of values:"))]
```

note that this is based on my best guess of what you are trying to do,  and I may not be understanding what you are trying to do